WPF DataGrid takes >1s to load for "few" data (40x40)
I am struggling to have reasonable load times for reasonable size DataGrids in WPF.
My example is super simple and pasted below. It simply loads a grid of 40x40 numbers when the button is pressed, and the UI is frozen for 1s. I have run the VS profiler, and it takes 1.16s to load the Layout (EDIT: with the window maximized - full screen!), which is built from 4147 elements in the visual tree.
I do not have any problem with the DataGrid taking time to load, but I do see as a problem that the Window is completely frozen while it loads. Can someone help me to load the DataGrid while keeping my window responsive?
Thank you very much!
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="Coliru.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:flap_ui_core.Components;assembly=flap_ui_core"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Coliru"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Create DataGrid" Padding="5,2" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="myContentControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Coliru
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class ViewModel
        {
            public class RowType
            {
                public ObservableCollection<double> Columns
                {
                    get => _Columns;
                }

                private ObservableCollection<double> _Columns;

                public RowType(ObservableCollection<double> columns)
                {
                    _Columns = columns;
                }
            }

            public static readonly int numcol = 40;
            public static readonly int numrow = 40;
            public ObservableCollection<RowType> Rows { get => _Rows; }
            private ObservableCollection<RowType> _Rows;


            public ViewModel()
            {
                 Random autoRand = new Random();
                _Rows = new ObservableCollection<RowType>();

                for (int icol = 0; icol < numcol;++icol)
                {
                    var rows = new ObservableCollection<double>();
                    for (int irow = 0; irow < numrow; ++irow)
                    {
                        rows.Add(autoRand.NextDouble());
                    }

                    _Rows.Add(new(rows));
                }

            }

        }

        DataGrid? dataGrid;
        ViewModel viewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new ViewModel();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGrid = new DataGrid();
            dataGrid.Initialized += DataGrid_Initialized;

            myContentControl.Content = dataGrid;
        }

        private void DataGrid_Initialized(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = viewModel.Rows;
            dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ViewModel.numcol; ++i)
            {
                var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
                var binding = new Binding();
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Columns[" + i + "]");
                col.Binding = binding;
                col.Header = "Column " + i;
                col.Width = 80;
                dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried many approaches, this is just a simplified version of the problem. I have tried MVVM as well.
EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is slow when loading in full window (maximized).
This is a snapshot of your updated version of the code (thank you for the update) in the profiler. It still takes 1.6s, compiled in Release mode.

You should check what takes so much time in there. Like probably creating bindings from code side or other stuff. Some of the code could be done in async way

Can you please be more specific? Thank you

Firstly I wouldn't subscribe to initialised. You could assign view model as data context of DataGrid and bind its itemssource to rows. Also you could move the AutoGenerateColumns back to initialisation of DataGrid instance. The whole thing is a bit wild. I would also generate columns at button click and not in DataGrid_Initialized. Honestly I would delete it and just use Binding and see how that works.

I tried running the code as you posted it, but I wasn't able to reproduce the long 1s delay.
The only real issue that I spotted wouldn't really rise to the level of a "problem" unless there were multiple button clicks involved: As things stand, every time you click the button, you subscribe again to the dataGrid.Initialized event and this isn't something that "goes out of scope". If it's the 2nd button click, then DataGrid_Initialized will run twice. If it's the 100th button click, DataGrid_Initialized will now run 100 times.
Here's a cleaner click handler that disconnects the event to ensure that you have only the one that you need.
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (myContentControl.Content is DataGrid existing)
        {
            existing.ItemsSource = null;
        }
        dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.Initialized += DataGrid_Initialized;
        myContentControl.Content = dataGrid;
    }
    finally
    {
        dataGrid.Initialized -= DataGrid_Initialized;
    }
}


Final code with revised Button_Click and minor simplifications.
You are showing us everything? There's no Debug logging or anything like that? Here's the code where I've tried to optimize out anything that might take any time. I want to be clear that I didn't find any smoking gun, however.


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
    new ViewModel DataContext => (ViewModel)base.DataContext;

    DataGrid? dataGrid;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            try
            {
                if (myContentControl.Content is DataGrid existing)
                {
                    existing.ItemsSource = null;
                }
                dataGrid = new DataGrid();
                dataGrid.Initialized += DataGrid_Initialized;
                myContentControl.Content = dataGrid;
            }
            finally
            {
                dataGrid.Initialized -= DataGrid_Initialized;
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show($@"Initialization took {stopwatch.Elapsed:ss\:ffff}"); 
        });
    }

    private void DataGrid_Initialized(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewModel.NUMCOL; ++i)
        {
            var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
            col.Binding = new Binding
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath("Columns[" + i + "]"),
            };
            col.Header = "Column " + i;
            col.Width = 80;
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
        }
        dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = DataContext.Rows;
    }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public class RowType
    {
        public ObservableCollection<double> Columns { get; }
        public RowType(ObservableCollection<double> columns)
        {
            Columns = columns;
        }
    }
    public const int NUMCOL = 40;
    public const int NUMROW = 40;
    public ObservableCollection<RowType> Rows { get; } = new ObservableCollection<RowType>();
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Random autoRand = new Random();

        for (int icol = 0; icol < NUMCOL; ++icol)
        {
            var rows = new ObservableCollection<double>();
            for (int irow = 0; irow < NUMROW; ++irow)
            {
                rows.Add(autoRand.NextDouble());
            }
            Rows.Add(new(rows));
        }
    }
}

Xaml
<Window x:Class="Coliru.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Coliru"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Create DataGrid" Padding="5,2" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="myContentControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

